# Which one is faster [if (x or y)] or [if x else if y]

Tags: javascript, performance

I need to check if date the user written is valid so i want to know what will be faster ?

```
if(dayOfManth > 12 || dayOfManth < 1) { return false; }
return true;
```

or

```
if(MonthOfYear > 12) { return false; }
if(MonthOfYear < 1)  { return false; }

return true;
```

the same is done for DayOfMonth(1-31) and others (year range, short month,FEB leap day,ect.)

What would be faster?

Comment: [Have you not got other things to optimize?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) If you're *really* that bothered, create a test case on http://jsperf.com and see.

Comment: What about `return dayOfMonth >= 1 && dayOfMonth <= 12;`?

Comment: It is faster to write and read the first.  I wouldn't sweat how fast the JavaScript interpreter is going to do the same until you prove that's a performance bottleneck in your code (which in this case I'll bet you a 6-pack it never will be).  Plus, I'd go even further and use Frédéric Hamidi's answer.  The result of the expression is a boolean value, and you're returning a boolean value, so just return the result of the expression.

Comment: there are many checks so it will not be readable.

Comment: I'll bet you that it doesn't make a significant difference.

Comment: Finally if all the answers are not satisfying - test it by yourself on  http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 5):

Simply use:

```
return dayOfMonth >= 1 && dayOfMonth <= 12
```

It's the most readable. Performance is ridiculously negligible in this case. Do not micro-optimize.

Comment: +1 for not returning boolean constants based on a boolean expression...

Comment: Would you do it for 20 checks?

Comment: If I had 20 expressions to evaluate, I would be much more concerned about readability than performance.

Comment: +1 vs the specific question asked.  Tho no need for parens here.  I've always considered parens to signify special handling, so it makes it *less* readable to me.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments on your question already say, performance shouldn't be a concern here.  So readability should be king.

From your comment on your question:

> there are many checks so it will not be readable

Then I recommend you use an option like this to split up your boolean expressions:

```
function someFunction(dayOfMonth, someOtherValue) {
    var result = true;
    result &= dayOfMonth >= 1;
    result &= dayOfMonth <= 12;
    result &= someOtherValue == 6;
    return result;
}

alert(someFunction(7, 6) ? "true" : "false"); // true
alert(someFunction(13, 6) ? "true" : "false"); // false
alert(someFunction(7, 5) ? "true" : "false"); // false
```

This uses the boolean `&=` operator to say "if the result is still true, and this expression is also true, then set the result to true.  Otherwise set it to false".

Performance aside, this will let you split all the expressions up, yet still let them be readable, and let you avoid repeating yourself as much as possible.

For readability I would still combine expressions when it makes sense, rather than putting a single expression on each line.  I just did it here to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: there are 2 readable options 1)spacing in code. 2) using    `||`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but if you mean the code sample I gave can be improved by those, I agree.  I'd combine `dayOfMonth` expressions.  Adding a newline before the return or after the initial `var result = true;` certainly wouldn't hurt readability.  The point of the answer was to suggest using the `&=` operator as another option.  It is better than multiple return statements, and better than cramming all expressions onto one line if you have many unrelated expression - more than the few you have in the question.

Comment: If you really have as few expressions as in the question, Yuval Adam's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Always choose the option which better expresses your intent. In this case, I find the first one much clearer than the second, though this is subjective.

Other than that, I'd use some form validation framework, so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

**EDIT**

Have never tried it, but looks promising:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: and what is validation framework?

Answer (score 0):

If this is user input validation there's no way such micro optimization would be noticeable and you should strive for code readability and maintainability as others have suggested.

Now just to answer your question. I don't believe there's any difference. The only optimization I would expect to be possible (on X86 architecture, can't say for others) is if you're logical expression could be compiled without using conditional jumps, thus avoiding unnecessary [branch mispredictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_misprediction). I don't think this can be done since you're using comparisons. If you are interested in learning more about such optimizations I wholeheartedly recommend you read [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

**They are both absolutely the same**. This looks like a mistaken case of **short-circuit evaluation** [<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

JavaScript uses (actually has) only short-circuit evaluation - if the first operand returns the minimal needed condition:

**The logical OR:**

`true || (true/false)` - only the first one is needed to be true to do short-circuit(best scenario);

`false || true` - now the second one is evaluated, because of the first one(worst scenario);

**The logical AND:**

`false && (true/false)` - whatever the second is, the result is false. The second condition is not evaluated(best scenario);

`true && true` - both are evaluated(worst scenario).

I've also made a little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7GYPh/) - the second test shows an extra alert(), because the second "condition" is evaluated.

Comment: Technically you're right. But in ABAP I found out that it's not really working like this. Therefore I wondered if in Javascript it also has a difference?

Comment: The only "not really working like this" is like the example - the side effect of a function. Your example is not concerning anything advanced to make something more.

Comment: So if I check 8 Dates inserted and i have 20 checks how long would it take?

Comment: For 8 dates - best case 8 checks, worst - 16. Time depends on the user's machine, unless you are using nodejs.

Comment: Even for worst case scenario with 160 checks on an old computer, with outdated javascript compiler I doubt it would take longer then 0.001 seconds.. Why not just give it a try ?

Comment: I did try , and I got a difference of a few seconds. What I want to know is it a mere coincidence or somthing real?